# iOS app detects unlock event while App is running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create an app like an Ads every time the user unlocks the phone.

The user unlocks the phone -> open customized ads.

Is this possible to capture the phone unlock event and open your app?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to capture the phone unlock event from within your app? -> **YES** |
Is it possible to open your app from the springboard? -> **NO** (assuming you are not looking to use private APIs)

Comment: Even if you could you shouldn't implement such feature, it would have been rather intrusive and annoying and got you nothing but angry users. Think about it, would you like a salesman waiting for you everytime you went home?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate... This is not possible.. iOS doesn't allow opening apps automatically ..

You have to add all the custom logics in your AppDelegate which will have your application life cycle delegate methods.

You can learn more about this on the [Apple Documentation Page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)